# change user and run ssh instruction in 1 line

Tags: linux, ssh

I'm trying to change my user to one that doesn't need password to run ssh instructions and then do exactly that, run an ssh instruction. What I have now is:

```
sudo su - testUser ssh testUser@server2 'cat /home/randomUser/hola.txt'
```

But I'm getting the answer:

```
/usr/bin/ssh: /usr/bin/ssh: cannot execute binary file
```

if I put the instructions in a different file called **testit** like this:

```
ssh testUser@server2

cat /home/randomUser/hola.txt
```

and I run:

```
sudo su - testUser < testit
```

it works!, but I need to use the one line instruction, someone know what should I change to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sudo su - testUser
```

why don't you use just `sudo -u testUser` as it is supposed to be used?

But anyway, manual pages for the tools you are using is a good start. For `sudo`:

```
sudo [...] [command]
```

This looks good and fits into your example.

For `su`:

```
su [options] [username]
```

Ola ... `su` does not have any argument `command`, unless you provide also `-c` switch, which is written also in the manual page. And it is `[option]`, so it should come in front of `[username]`! Something like this should do the job:

```
sudo su -l -c "ssh testUser@server2 'cat /home/randomUser/hola.txt'" testUser
```

but as I already mentioned, it can be significantly simplified by using `sudo` only:

```
sudo -i -u testUser "ssh testUser@server2 'cat /home/randomUser/hola.txt'"
```

Comment: the second line throw me the answer:
sudo: unknown user: i
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
But the first line run perfectly that's enough for me 

Thank you so much!